# python import shares common values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Might sound beginner-ish, but here goes.

I am importing a `Typedef` script which contains variables which are used and called throughout my program. I do this by simply calling `'import Typedef'` on all scripts within the package/workspace.

Now I change a variable in `Typedef` in one of the scripts by calling:

```
Typedef.myVariable = newVariable
```

Will this change be reflected if the other scripts reference this variable?

If not, what should I do to rectify this?

If it helps, I'm using Python 3.4, coding using Anaconda's Spyder.

Comment: "_Will this change be reflected if the other scripts reference this variable?_" I suggest the empirical approach: "try it and see" ;-)

Comment: Yes, it will if the other scripts are imported simultaneously. I often use this technique across my Pygame programs, creating a data class that all other classes can import, change, and interact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as said in the comments.

You just have to take care of constructs like

`from TypeDef import myvariable` - in that case, myvariable is a new name
pointing to the value of the variable at import time, and won't be "seeing" updates to new values for `TypeDef.myvariable`.

Once you assign a name for an object in a local namespace (or "global" namespace - in Python, globals are actually "module locals") that name points to that particular object.

Just use that with care, and be sure to document such usage in your project. This is what is mostly used in Python instead of "Singletons"  needed in static languages.

Also, the technique can be used to change actually functions or classes in other modules - that is what is called "Monkey patching". (Not good, in general, for production code - and excelent on the other hand for testing code, where you monkey patch dependencies of the function being tested with mock objects)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because variables in your `Typedef` module are in the module scope, which will be available wherever that module is imported.

For some further reading, take a look at [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).